# how to enable windowWillResize after awakeFromNib

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, nswindow

I initialize the window by awakeFromNib,and I hope when I resize the window,it's width and height will double.The code run correctly at first,but at the second time it appears with doubled size,so I wonder how to forbid windowWillResize until I resize it,it seems awakeFromNib doesn't work.Here's the code:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    width = 388.0;
    height = 273.0;
    NSRect rect = window.frame;
    NSSize size;
    size.width = width;
    size.height = height;
    rect.size = size;
    [window setFrame:rect display:YES];    
    [window setDelegate:self];
}
-(NSSize)windowWillResize:(NSWindow *)sender toSize:(NSSize)frameSize{
    float rwidth = [window frame].size.width;
    float rheight = [window frame].size.height;
    if(rwidth<=width*2 && rheight<=height*2){
        NSRect rect = window.frame;
        NSSize size;
        size.width = width*2;
        size.height = height*2;
        rect.size = size;
        [window setFrame:rect display:YES];
        [window setMinSize:[window frame].size];
        [window setMaxSize:[window frame].size];
    }
    return frameSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller should implement the NSWindowDelegate protocol in your header file

```
// MyController.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyController : NSViewController <NSWindowDelegate>
-(void) awakeFromNib;
-(NSSize) windowWillResize:(NSWindow *)sender toSize:(NSSize)frameSize;
@end
```